# Collapse cell groups when you close parent group?

Tags: stylesheet, cells

I have a particularly long notebook. Here's what I'd like to do: to say in my stylesheet that upon closing certain types of cell-groups that all the cell-groups inside should close as well. That way the next time I open the cell, it will show me all the next top level cells enclosed.

Comment: It's not exactly as automated as you would like, but in a pinch could you use "Cell -> Grouping -> Close All Subgroups"? On Win its associated with `CTRL + }`.